# cannot access session variable set in prior middleware in the next middleware. during the same request

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have This issue where If a request comes in, and I set a session variable from a db query inside a middleware. In the next Middleware, the session variable comes up as Undefined.

But when I run the Request again, it works.

Please how do I fix it. The data stored in the  session variable in the the previous middleware, is very important and needed for the next middleware to work.

So im thinking is it that you cannot set a session variable and access it during the same request cycle ?

please see code below

first middlware

```
function(req, res, next) {
    Clients.findOne({subdomain: req.subdomains[0]}, function (err, client) {
            if(!err){
                if(!client){
                    //res.send(client);
                    res.send(403, 'Sorry! you cant see that.');
                }
                else{

                    //console.log(client);
                    req.session.Client = client;
                    //console.log(req.session.Client.dbUrl); even this console log shows undefined.
                    next();
                }
            }

    }
```

Second Middleware

```
function(req, res, next){
      console.log(req.session.Client.dbUrl);
      next();
 }
```

in the first middleware, the console.log shows undefined after setting the session.Client to Client also.
in the Second Middleware, the console.log comes up as undefined.

Ok i think i have narrowed it down to the setting of the session variable. I did a test to set req.session.test to a string, and that works but req.session.Client

Thank you.

Comment: To whom ever that downvoted this, at least have the decency to explain why

Comment: Why are you calling `next()` twice when `client` is set? You should just add a `return;` right before the end of your `if (!err) {}` block.

Comment: Thank you mcsdex . The  second next(), please ignore it, was from code that i removed so we can focus on the relevant code.

Comment: Is it possible the middleware isn't running in the order that you think it is?

Comment: Thank you again msdex for taken your time to reply. But the return statement didnt seem to help.

Comment: is your session variable created in that spot or doest already exists if is a new variable define it like req.session={Client:client}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I dont know how to ensure that my middleware run in the order that i want except listing them in order in app.js

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, yes its created at that spot. I will try your suggestion. Thank you